# What's the purpose of start/end parameters to str.endswith()/startswith()?

Tags: python, string

I don't seem to understand how I should use `start`/`end` parameters to [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith). Is there a simple rule I can follow?

Also, is there any benefit to using these functions compared to using string slices?

Comment: `str.startswith('abc', 2) == str[2:].startswith('abc')`. I guess adjusting the internal start compare is 'cheaper' than creating an explicit new string through slicing.

Comment: Also you are comparing boolean-values as to strings when using slices. Which is faster.

Comment: str.startswith() allows you to do a search for a particular substring at the head or tail of the original string. Have many use cases for file types in a file name, much simple that regex. It also allows you to check when the length of the string is shorter than the target substring. Also avoids error being thrown when length of string is shorter than the start/end index as compared to slicing.

Comment: You already have an answer [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-startswith-endswidth-function/).

Comment: I think its personal choice mostly, but you always want a function version of python's tricky things that can be passed as a function object to other bits of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `str.startswith()` and `str.endswith()` with their mentioned parameters `start` and `end` are there to increase readability in the code and to take out complexity that you get by slicing.

```py
text = "afoobarstring"
part_to_check = "bar"
position = 4

# approach 1 (startswith)
text.startswith(part_to_check, position)

# approach 2 (slicing)
text[position:position + len(part_to_check)] == part_to_check

# approach 3 (startswith and slicing)
text[position:].startswith(part_to_check)
```

While the three approaches do roughly the same thing, the approach 1 is simply easier to read and understand as the other approaches (imho). In approach 2 you also have to compute the end position of the string, and in approach 3 you have a copy of the string (as in approach 2) and the same function call as in approach 1 in addition.

I suspect that this leads also to better results regarding the time measurements:

```py
In [1]: import timeit                                                           

In [2]: timeit.timeit('text="afoobarstring"; part_to_check = "bar"; position = 4; text.startswith(part_to_check, position)', number=10000000)                                        
Out[2]: 1.6531553190034174

In [3]: timeit.timeit('text="afoobarstring"; part_to_check = "bar"; position = 4; text[position:position + len(part_to_check)] == part_to_check', number=10000000)                   
Out[3]: 1.8180583719986316

In [4]: timeit.timeit('text="afoobarstring"; part_to_check = "bar"; position = 4; text[position:].startswith(part_to_check)', number=10000000)
Out[4]: 2.349334787999396
```

And also I think that approach 1 is much cleaner, also under the hood:

```py
In [1]: import dis                                                              

In [2]: def startswith(): 
   ...:     text="afoobarstring" 
   ...:     part_to_check = "bar" 
   ...:     position = 4 
   ...:     return text.startswith(part_to_check, position) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [3]: def slicing(): 
   ...:     text="afoobarstring" 
   ...:     part_to_check = "bar" 
   ...:     position = 4 
   ...:     return text[position:position + len(part_to_check)] == part_to_check 
   ...:                                                                                                      

In [4]: def slicing_and_startswith(): 
   ...:     text="afoobarstring" 
   ...:     part_to_check = "bar" 
   ...:     position = 4 
   ...:     return text[position:].startswith(part_to_check) 
   ...:                                                                                                      

In [5]: dis.dis(startswith)                                                                                  
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('afoobarstring')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (text)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (part_to_check)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (position)

  5          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (text)
             21 LOAD_ATTR                0 (startswith)
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (part_to_check)
             27 LOAD_FAST                2 (position)
             30 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             33 RETURN_VALUE

In [6]: dis.dis(slicing)                                                                                     
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('afoobarstring')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (text)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (part_to_check)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (position)

  5          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (text)
             21 LOAD_FAST                2 (position)
             24 LOAD_FAST                2 (position)
             27 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
             30 LOAD_FAST                1 (part_to_check)
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             36 BINARY_ADD
             37 BUILD_SLICE              2
             40 BINARY_SUBSCR
             41 LOAD_FAST                1 (part_to_check)
             44 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             47 RETURN_VALUE

In [7]: dis.dis(slicing_and_startswith)                                                                      
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('afoobarstring')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (text)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (part_to_check)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             15 STORE_FAST               2 (position)

  5          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (text)
             21 LOAD_FAST                2 (position)
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 BUILD_SLICE              2
             30 BINARY_SUBSCR
             31 LOAD_ATTR                0 (startswith)
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (part_to_check)
             37 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

I think it is similar with the `endswith()`-method. That's why I didn't show this one separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
strg = "abcdefghi"

print(strg.endswith("ghi")) # True
print(strg.endswith("def", 1, 6)) # True
```

the last statement is the same as

```
print(strg[1:6].endswith("def")  # True
```

except that it will not create a fresh string (which the slice `strg[1:6] = "bcdef"` does).

Answer (score 0):

startswith/endwith have the purpose of finding some substring at the beginning or at the end of some string.

The start and end parameters have the purpose of 'sliding' the window where you may find the substring. Works as parameters so the startswith/endswith can be applied to find any substring in any specific position.